# CD-ing a file to itself

Tags: terminal, applications, applescript, automator, preview

I wrote an application in Applescript to open a black picture and fullscreen it in preview. I need the app to "cd" to itself, no matter where it is. That means if it is on the desktop it can pull up that picture from within the apps files, and if the app is moved somewhere else, it can still pull that picture from within the app. Should the app just create a directory in the Application Support folder or is this possible?

Comment: Could you specify within your question how the "wherever it may be" might be known? Is it defined by your application installer, is it random, is it `~/Applications`?

Comment: Could you please clarify your need **within** your question rather than within **comments** which will go away.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly all you need is to get the current directory of the application.
Quick looking through SE answers pulls out this:

> set YourPathVariable to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")